# EF Core seeding user data getting duplicate role in users table warning

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I am seeding test data that I always want their I am getting the issue

The error I am getting is but why when my user and roles is empty , I am using Ef Core 5

> The seed entity for entity type 'IdentityUserRole' cannot be
> added because another seed entity with the same key value for
> {'UserId', 'RoleId'} has already been added. Consider using
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> conflicting key values.

```
public class UsersWithRolesConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserRole<string>>
{
        private const string adminId = "B22698B8-42A2-4115-9631-1C2D1E2AC5F7";
        private const string TestUser1Id = "7796F3F2-5600-40A8-99B4-832EE57DC7E1";
        private const string TestUser2Id = "4F75BBA1-1CDF-44A7-84DF-D0C617E5E19D";
        private const string ClubSuperAdminRole = "f95d8e54-ab12-406b-973b-ab92d4cab72a";
        private const string ClubUserRole = "c2f9a56d-4e18-4d38-8eab-7a141895b049";
        private const string ClubModRole = "65f1941d-048a-4b02-ad8e-1757e392aad8";
        private const string Admin = "20ab180a-70cf-48b9-9315-4308b385b83f";

        IdentityUserRole<string> TestUser2Roles = new IdentityUserRole<string>
        {
            RoleId = ClubUserRole,
            UserId = TestUser2Id,
        };

        builder.HasData(TestUser2Roles);


        IdentityUserRole<string> TestUser1Roles = new IdentityUserRole<string>
        {
            RoleId = ClubModRole,
            UserId = TestUser1Id,
        };

        builder.HasData(TestUser2Roles);
}
```

Here is the data

[image]

And here you see the role are empty

[image]

And I am using

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Club>().Property(x => x.ClubId).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");


    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper() });
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "ClubSuperAdmin", NormalizedName = "SuperAdmin".ToUpper() });
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "ClubMod", NormalizedName = "ClubMod".ToUpper() });
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "ClubUser", NormalizedName = "ClubUser".ToUpper() });

   //modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AdminConfiguration());
   //modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TestUser1Seeder());
   //modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TestUser2Seeder());
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UsersWithRolesConfig());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo. In the last line of your fist code example you are doing `builder.HasData(TestUser2Roles);` while it should be `builder.HasData(TestUser1Roles);`. Otherwise `TestUser2Roles` will be added two times and the exception occurs.